# Django - no such column: blog_comment.body error

Tags: django, django-models

I am following a tutorial as I am fairly new to Django, and I am trying to add a comments system to my blog. However, whenever I try and use it I get an error message saying the following:`no such column: blog_comment.body`. I am not sure what is going on, as in my model I have `body = models.TextField()`, and I am just generally very confused.

Comment: Just `./manage.py makemigrations` **and** `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Comes up with an error message saying body is a non-nullable field and that I can't add it to comment (the model) without a default.

Comment: Since it's not nullable, Django asks you to enter a default value. Go ahead and do it. Otherwise, if you don't want to enter a default, write it like this `body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)` and then run the same commads.

Comment: Perfect - if you add that as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: Thank you, just added it with a little more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have not run migrations in order to apply the `body` column to the database.

Just run `./manage.py makemigrations` **and** `./manage.py migrate`

Django will ask you to enter a default value since you have declared the `body` field as not nullable.

If you don't want to enter a default value, write it like this:

```
body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and then run the same commads.